# Mkdir(): Permission denied no Windows

Tags: php, laravel, windows

Tento configurar o VueJS no laravel com o seguinte código:

```
php artisan preset vue
```

Porém, me retona esse erro:

```
ErrorException : mkdir(): Permission denied
```

Estou usando Windows e meu projeto fica nesse caminho `C:\projLarVue`

Obs: O mesmo comando para bootstrap funciona. Meu Laravel é 5.7.26

Comment: Resolvi o problema liberando acesso em 'botão direito encima da pasta>Segurança>Controle Total(Marcar)'. Fica a dica pros que sofreram o mesmo que eu ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu problema é relacionado a permissão de diretório, e para isso você pode utilizar o comando `cacls` do terminal para isso (similar ao o chmod do linux), por exemplo:

```
CACLS *.* /E /T /C /P todos:F
```

`CACLS`  Exibe/modifica listas de controle de acesso (ACLs) de arquivos *(é uma espécie de chmod do linux)*

**Parâmetros**

`*.*` Defino que são todos os arquivos da raiz aonde estou executando o comando, mas pode ser subsistido por um diretório ou um arquivo especifico.

**/E** – Edita as permissões

**/P** – Substitui os  direitos ao usuário especificado

**/D** – Nega Acesso ao usuário especificado

**/T** - Altera ACLs de arqs. especificados no dir. e nos subdirs

**todos** é o nome do usuário, e o que vem após os ":" são as permissões, por exemplo:
`todos:F` concede permissão total, As opções são:

**R**  Ler

**W**  Gravar

**C**  Alterar (gravar)

**F**  Controle total

Para mais informações você pode rodar o comando

```
CACLS /h
```